# Where is the correct place to make HTTP requests in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, httprequest, nsurlsession

I have an app that fetches data from a server using `NSURLSessionDataTask`. As of right now I am starting my `HTTP` `GET` Request in the `init` method of the `UIViewController` that displays the data. Is this the best/smartest place to kick off an `HTTP` request? If not, where should I do it?

I'm asking this question because when I exit my app and it goes into the background (and is not killed) and then re-open my application, the `HTTP` request is not fired off (because it is in the `UIViewControllers` `init` method) and the data being displayed is not up to date with what's on the server. I've tried putting it in `viewDidLoad` but this method is not called upon entering the foreground, neither is `viewWillAppear` nor `viewDidAppear`.

Should I be doing all of my `HTTP` requests in one of the `UIApplications` life cycle methods in my `appDelegate`?

In short, where is the best place to make `HTTP` requests in `iOS`?

Thank you, I can post code or explain more if needed.

Comment: Why not create a custom object to handle all of the requests? The easiest would be a subclass of `NSObject`.

Comment: If your application contain more then one viewControllers you should put HTTP request to appDelegate and call it in didFinishLaunching Method and store all the data in to NSMutableDictionary and use it in all the viewControllers ,and you can call this method in didEnterForground method so all the data will refresh every time when forground the app. you can ask if any quary.

Comment: Alright, I was thinking of putting it in the `didEnterForground` method. Thank you

Comment: viewWillAppear should get called when you quit and launch the app.. just curious why its not called. :-/

Comment: @jithinroy viewWillAppear is unreliable in my experience. Best to avoid it, as there are many situations it will not be called in.

Comment: My `UIViewControllers` are held in a `UIPageViewController` so this may be why their `viewWillAppear`s are not being called.

Answer (score 2):

first off, this is a huge question and probably impossible to answer fully here, but hopefully I can point you in the right direction so you can learn how to fish. :)

To stick to the Model-View-Controller paradigm, you will want to create a separate object for making your HTTP requests. An HTTP request would be considered part of your model. The benefit of this is being able to use your model in other iOS apps you create, for example.

As for where to put all of this stuff and what's the best design.... One thing that strikes me in your question is you want the data being displayed in your app to be up to date with what is on the server. On a high level, a really good way to do this is to use iOS's ability to multitask and perform functions for you when you app is in the background. You would need to register with the OS as an app that performs fetches to a server in the background.

According to Apple's documentation, "In Xcode 5 and later, you declare the background modes your app supports from the Capabilities tab of your project settings. Enabling the Background Modes option adds the UIBackgroundModes key to your app’s Info.plist file." From there you would need to research the UIApplicationDelegate's protocol methods **– application:performFetchWithCompletionHandler:** and **-application:handleEventsForBackgroundURLSession:completionHandler:**.

Also, you will need to look into NSURLSession a little more. If you want to use background fetching, NSURLSessionDataTask is not supported. You will need to use NSURLSessionDownloadTask, save the response to a file and process it however you need to. Also, as the app delegate method name above implies, you will need to read the NSURLSessionConfiguration Class Reference, specifically about **backgroundSessionConfiguration**.

The really cool thing about all of this is, after you have implemented it, your app UI will be up to date for the user – even if your app was killed by the user or by the OS. Pretty nifty.

Good luck and hope this all helps. I hope I didn't miss any other big pieces here.

Comment: Thank you this is very helpful, I'll look into multitasking more.

Answer (score 1):

I think it a personal preference. So I personally do it on the model objects. Lets say I have a Car object and a ShowroomViewController. I always declare a class method to Car object to call service to get all the cars.

```
@interaface Car

+(void)fetchCarsWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(NSArray* cars, NSError *error ))handler;

-(void)getDetailsWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(Car* car, NSError *error ))handler;
@end
```

Then call the class method on viewWillAppear(If I need to update the cars very often) or viewDidload(If I need to call the service once).

The other trick I mostly do is define a flag in the view controller like

```
@interface ShowroomViewController
@property(assign)BOOL needsModelUpdate;
@end
```

and I update the modal conditionally.

```
@implementation ShowroomViewController
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    if(self.needsModelUpdate){
       [self fetchModel]
    }
}



-(void)fetchModel{
     __block __weak ShowroomViewController *weakRef=self;
     [Car fetchCarsWithCompletionHandler:^(NSArray *cars, NSError *error) {
            [weakRef setCars:cars];
            [weakRef.tableView reloadData];
     }];
}
@end
```

The reason I define this flag is I can change it somewhere else lets say applicationDidEnterBackground: method the change the flag. Or you can use KVO but I always find it overkill .

Answer (score 0):

Do it however you want.

Personally, I create a class specifically for all communication with the server. Actually, my App has around 20 classes for different parts of the communication process. But yours is probably less complicated.

Add an instance of the class as an object in an xib file or else create an instance of it inside the app delegate's init method.

Use didEnterForeground to tell the other class that it needs to do it's stuff, but still use the init method to create an instance of the class.